# Coagulation factors and rheumatoid arthritis

Tags: inflammation, arthritis, blood-clotting, rheumatology

A doctor once explained to me that elevated values of factor XIII and van Willebrand factor can be caused by rheumatoid arthritis.

I didn't get around to asking back then, but is that something specific to rheumatoid arthritis or something that's normal during any kind of inflammation? And is it something that's only elevated during an acute episode of RA or does it stay elevated?

Comment: What did your preliminary research show you about whether they are acute phase reactants in other inflammatory processes?